# Is this a genetic algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am trying to make a genetic algorithm that finds the word given in the console input. But I don't know if I succeeded to do a full genetic algorithm.
Here is the code:

main.py:

```
from population import Population

target = input()
maxPop = 10
mutation = 100

print("\n\n\n")

pop = Population(target, maxPop, mutation)
```

population.py:

```
import random
from ADN import genetic

class Population:
    def __init__(self, target, maxPop, mut):
        adn = genetic()
        self.popul = []
        i = 0
        while i < maxPop:
            self.popul.append(adn.genFirst(len(target)))
            print(self.popul[i])
            i+=1

        #oldPop = self.popul
        #adn.fitness(oldPop, target)
        #"""
        while target not in self.popul:
            oldPop = self.popul
            self.popul = adn.fitness(oldPop, target)
            if target in self.popul:
                return
        #"""
```

ADN.py:

```
import random

class genetic:
    def genFirst(self, length):
        bestGenes = ""
        self.letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890[],. "
        word = ""
        i = 0
        while i < length:
            word += random.choice(self.letters)
            i+=1
        return word

    def fitness(self, oldPop, target):
        newPop = []

        j = 0
        for word in oldPop:
            newW = ""
            for letter in word:
                if(letter not in target):
                    letter = random.choice(self.letters)
                else:
                    if(target.index(letter) != word.index(letter)):
                        letter = random.choice(self.letters)
                newW += letter
            newPop.append(newW)

        print(newPop)
        return newPop
```

If it is not a full genetic algorithm, what is missing?

Comment: There is no strict "template" for a genetic algorithm, so it is unclear where is the distinction between the "full" one and the non-"full".

Comment: Since you seem to lack both a mutation operator and a crossover operator, why do you think that it qualifies as a genetic algorithm? It seems like it is a decent *start*.

Comment: I thought crossover was done when thecorrect letter was transmitted to the next generaion

Comment: The comments must be helpful enough. Too broad to make an answer.

Comment: Even though you have a function that you call "fitness", you don't really have a fitness function as that it is typically understood in the literature. Even though as @EugeneSh. rightly points out, there is no such thing as an official standard for what counts as a genetic algorithm, it would be a stretch to call your code a genetic algorithm. The answer to the question "what is it missing?" is "just about everything" (a fitness function, a selection operator, a mutation operator and a crossover operator). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm

Comment: Thank you. I will read and make a new algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a genetic algorithm. It is not even an evolutionary algorithm. It misses the fitness function which should calculate how good is every member of the calculation. After that you should decide which code would you want to make: genetic or evolutionary. Being a beginner you should try the evolutionary algorithm, it's easier and it does not contain the crossover function (which is difficult for beginners).
Try this:

```
import random

genes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrsttuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ+-[]()1234567890;<>?/ "
target = input()

def genPar(length):
    parent = []
    for i in range(length):
        parent.append(random.choice(genes))

    return "".join(parent)

def fitness(parent):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(parent)):
        if(parent[i] == target[i]):
            total += 1
    return total

def mutate(parent):
    index  = random.choice(range(len(parent)))
    child = []

    for i in range(len(parent)):
        if(i == index):
            letter = random.choice(genes)
        else:
            letter = parent[i]
        child.append(letter)

    return "".join(child)

parent = genPar(len(target))
bestPar = parent
bestFitness = fitness(parent)

print(parent)

generations = 1

while True:
    child = mutate(bestPar)
    childFit = fitness(child)

    if(childFit > bestFitness):
        bestFitness = childFit
        bestPar = child

    print(child)
    generations += 1

    if(child == target):
        break

print("\nGenerations: " + str(generations))
```

Answer (score 0):

Until u see Initialization -> Fitness -> Genetic operators (mutation, crossover) -> Fitness -> Substitution  cycle you can't say it is Genetic/Evolutionary algorithm :)...

Answer (score 0):

for the basic genetic algorithm, you need to use some operator selection, fitness, mutation, crossover.
there different types of selection, crossover, and mutation that you can use based on your problem.
a simple example of crossover and mutation.

```
def single_point_crossover(parent1,parent2):
        crossover_point = random.randint(1,9)
        #print("crossover point", crossover_point)
        child_1 = np.hstack((parent1[0:crossover_point], parent2[crossover_point:]))
        child_2 = np.hstack((parent2[:crossover_point],parent1[crossover_point:]))
        return child_1,child_2 


def mutation(parent1,parent2):
    n = len(parent1)
    pos_1 = random.randint(0,n-1)
    pos_2 = random.randint(0,n-1)
    #print(pos_1, pos_2)
    def swap(sol, posA, posB):
        result = sol.copy()
        elA = sol[posA]
        elB = sol[posB]
        result[posA] = elB
        result[posB] = elA
        return result
    child1 = swap(parent1, pos_1, pos_2)
    child2 = swap(parent2, pos_1, pos_2)
    return child1,child2
```